# Add object to output of swashbuckle/swagger JSON

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have a webapi project configured with swagger, and I need every endpoint to have their own ID, for documentation and consumption purposes.

I would like this ID to be exposed through swagger and in the swashbuckle UI.

The best approach I can find is to create an attribute and operation filter, and have swashbuckle add it to the operation.description text, but I'd prefer for it to:

a) be its own JSON object in the generated swagger  obj, and
b) have its own section in the UI (not 'hack' it into a h4 in the description)

Does anyone know if this is possible?
thanks

Comment: can you be clear on the requirement with some examples? is it like you need to add one parameter to all the methods?